# Selma converter and unit test

Tags: java, eclipse, junit, converters

I'm running into trouble using Selma converter in my classic maven project (I'm using eclipse)

I created my converter, Selma generate the needed class in my target folder, that's fine

then I'm trying to write a unit test of that converter, it's calling selma to get the converter and there I'm getting a class not found exception. junit can't find the generated class.

what can I do ? When i run a unit test from eclipse I want it to use my classic source folder and also what have been generated by selma

Comment: Hello there, I'm in the same situation. Did you find any solution to this issue?

Comment: No luck with this one, still have no solution

Comment: I'm really banging my head on the wall on this one and now I'm finding problems with basic Selma usage as well and I'm getting confused :D

Comment: actually I can remember that I fixed my issue when i started using intelliJ ...

Comment: Mmmm interesting a lot of people in my company are using intelliJ, but I still think that Selma guy should have a processor that works with out of the box Eclipse :D

Answer (score 0):

when you use Selma inside eclipse without Maven, you should add both processor and api jar to the path of the annotation processor plugin.
This way Eclipse will take care of using the annotation processor when compiling the project and so the generated class will be available at runtime for Junit.
This should be somewhere in project settings, see plugin documentation for this purpose: https://www.eclipse.org/jdt/apt/introToAPT.php .

Comment: thanks for your answer but Annottaion processing is well enabled in my project and still nothing happen. I'm actually using maven.

Comment: if I run a mvn clean compile, mappers get generated but unless I run this command manually eclipse isn't doing anything